# How to add text to a force directed graph in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I've been using the network graph example here:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I am trying to add text elements onto the nodes but can't seem to get it to appear next to the nodes.

I tried to add the following lines in the function below but athat this does it to display the text on the top left of the screen - while i'd expect it to appear on the top left.

Not sure if anyone could help?

```
var textElements = svg.append("g")
 .selectAll('text')
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append('text').attr('font-size', 15)
.attr('dx', 15)
.attr('dy', 4)
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

Original:

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });



    var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

   node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; });


  simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
  .links(graph.links);



function ticked() {
link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this guy that solved this:

```
myText.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/UwQfPscQiOg87IEMYtET?p=preview